# How do I understand this probability notation?

Tags: probability, notation, self-learning

Say we have $ x \in R$  and a random variable $ X$.

My lecture notes say that if we look at the following event:

$$ \{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) = x\} = X^{-1}(x)$$ we can call it the event "$X = x$", and can calculate its probabilty accordingly:

$$ \Pr\lbrack X=x\rbrack = \Pr\lbrack X^{-1}(x)\rbrack = \Pr\lbrack \{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) = x\} $$

Which does not make sense to be because as I do not undestand what $X^{-1}$ means, can anyone clear this up ?

Comment: Which is the question?

Comment: what is the meaning of $ X ^{-1}$ ?

Comment: You have written the definition: the set of all events whose probability is exactly $x$.

Comment: so I should read it like "inverse of X(x) is a subset of $\Omega$ where the probability of each item is X " ?

Comment: $X^{-1}(x)$ is the set of values in the probability space that $X$ maps to $x$. This is the set of outcomes which, if they occurred and you measured $X$, the measurement you would get would be $x$. This "inverse" notation is called the pre-image and is standard across mathematics. You can think of the left side as the definition of the right side.

Comment: @zython Read this way instead " $X^{-1}(x) $ is a subset of $\Omega$, all of whose elements are mapped to $x$ by the function X".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lesson of the lecture is that a random variable $X$ is a function on a probability space.  The notation $X^{-1}(x)$ means the pre-image of the value $x$, that is, the set of everything in the probability space that maps to the same value $x$.

Comment: makes sense, accepted

Answer (score 0):

Say you throw a pair of three-sided dice, so each outcome is $1,$ $2,$ or $3.$

The possible outcomes are:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc} (1,1) & (1,2) & (1,3) \\ (2,1) & (2,2) & (2,3) \\ (3,1) & (3,2) & (3,3) \end{array}
$$
Let $X$ be the maximum of the numbers shown by the two dice.

$$
\Pr(X=3) = \Pr(X^{-1}(3)) = \Pr(\{(1,3), (2,3), (3,3),(3,2),(3,1)\}).
$$

The set $X^{-1}(3)$ is the set of all outcomes for which $X=3$ , i.e. it is this set of five outcomes:
$$
X^{-1}(3) = \{(1,3), (2,3), (3,3),(3,2),(3,1)\}.
$$

Comment: thanks for the great answer kimchilover beat you too it though